# GoogleAPIs: get files from a TeamDrive

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I need to get the files from a specific team drive in google drive using the Google APIs .NET library version 3 (in C#)

I can select all the files in a Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService using `DriveService.Files.List().Execute()`
I can get a specific drive from the same Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService using `DriveService.TeamDrives.List().Execute().TeamDrives.FirstOrDefault(drv => drv.Id == folderID)` [in this case folderID is of course a string variable for the google team drive's ID]
I just need to loop through the files [Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File as would be returned above in the `Files.List().Execute()`] in that specific Team Drive but there seems to be no child parameters or functions in the TeamDrive object to access files

How do I retrieve the files from that specific TeamDrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the files under your shared drive/team drive, You need to use [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and set the necessary parameters:

> **corpora**: "drive"
>
> **driveId**: ID of the shared drive to search
>
> **includeItemsFromAllDrives**: true
>
> **supportsAllDrives**: true

### Sample Code:

```
var request = DriveService.Files.List();
request.Corpora = "drive";
request.DriveId = folderID;
request.IncludeItemsFromAllDrives = true;
request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
var result = request.Execute();
```

### Reference:

- [.NET Google.Apis.Drive.v3 - Class FilesResource.ListRequest](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest.html)